# Error trying to train RNN network. ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_20 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, ocr, recurrent-neural-network

I'am new on this topic about training images. I have two directory with train and test images of handwriting characters. I'am trying to train with RNN network but i have this error on fit_generator function.

The code look like this:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = '/datasets/training',
    target_size = (32,32),
    batch_size = 32,
    class_mode = 'categorical'

)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = '/testing',
    target_size = (32,32),
    batch_size = 32,
    class_mode = 'categorical'

)

model = Sequential()
model.add(
    LSTM(32,
        activation='relu',
        input_shape=(32,32))
)
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="Adam", metrics=['acc'])

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                         steps_per_epoch = 16,
                         epochs = 18,
                         validation_data = test_generator,
                         validation_steps = 16)
```

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_20 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, None, None, None)

Comment: Is it RNN or CNN?

Comment: why `.compole` two times?

Comment: Sorry about 2 .compile... i want a RNN. what part of code conduct to CNN? I'am new on this topic

Comment: Please follow this OCR tutorials, https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/